# Testing: insert value passed into Action<T>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, action

How do you use *Rhino Mocks* to insert a value into an action?

`Register()` takes an action that is assigned to a local variable that is used later in the function:

```
var result = EnumResult.Timeout;

something.Register<EnumResult>(r => result = r);

<do things with result which need to be unit tested>
```

I want to be able to inject a value as *r* into the action (as it is defined in the function) and test what happens afterwards.

Comment: @I Clark Can you explain a bit more of your testing scenario? It seems as though you're asking how to get the local variable named result packaged into a lambda when you don't have access to that local variable from your testing environment. I guess if this is a pure mocking scenario, I'm wondering why the lambda needs to be invoked - it seems like the argument needs to be verified in some way shape or form; something along the lines of Expect.Call(()=>mockedSomething.Register<EnumResult>(null)).Constraints(Is.Matching<Action<??>>(c=>c.YourVerificationCodeHere));  Am I on the right track here?

Comment: @J Trana: Hi. I want to be able to control the value of _r_ that assigned to _result_ in the callback Action of `Register()` in my unit tests. I am not testing the `Register()` function itself but rather the actions performed after _result_ has been assigned to. RE: invoke: this is the only way I have gotten tests to run instead of throwing _null_ exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just pass a lambda in your test that sets some variable and then validate the variable was set at the end of the test?  Something like this:

```
var wasCalled = false;
mock.Stub(s => s.Register(r => wasCalled = true);
...
Assert.IsTrue(wasCalled);
```

This will ensure your "Register" method is calling the lambda that is passed to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately my original question didn't ask what I wanted to ask and I have re-worked it. Would you mind having a look again?

Comment: Even based on your edits, I still think my code example shows what you're asking for: A stub that sets a local variable.  Perhaps if you showed the definition of the "something" class along with your unit test as you currently have it, we could provide more valuable answers.